# Reasons for getting the Program Compatibility Assistant dialog?

Tags: windows-7, uac, compatibility

**What are possible reasons for getting the Program Compatibility Assistant dialog after my application closes?**

[image: Program Compatibility Assistant image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC5958.gif))</sub>

**EDIT: [Program Compatibility Assistant: frequently asked questions](https://support.microsoft.com/hub/4338813/windows-help)**

I realize this question has already been asked on S.O.

- [Program Compatibility Assistant thinks my app is an installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577412/program-compatibility-assistant-thinks-my-app-is-an-installer)
- [Windows 7 Program Compatibility Assistant appeared for my app. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069750/windows-7-program-compatibility-assistant-appeared-for-my-app-why)
- [Why I receive a message from the Program Compatibility Assistant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806017/why-i-receive-a-message-from-the-program-compatibility-assistant)
- [How do I prevent programmatically the “Program Compatibility Assistant” in Vista (and Windows 7) from appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587962/how-do-i-prevent-programmatically-the-program-compatibility-assistant-in-vista)

However, my app:

1. Only gets *PCA* after it closes
2. Does not attempt to do anything that requires elevated privileges (I don't think)
3. Does not get *PCA* when run from IDE
4. Is not an installer/setup program
5. Does not have "installer" or "setup" in the program name
6. Does not throw an exception when it closes, or exit with a code other than 0 (I don't think)
7. Does not get *PCA* if I add `<compatibility>` node to application manifest

Note #6, with the following app.manifest, I no longer get the PCA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

So that second part seems to fix it, but I am worried that my application is still doing something that I am unaware of.

**To be clear, I'm asking a 2 part question:**

1. **What issues can cause the PCA dialog to appear?**
2. **Is the `<compatibility>` node absolutely necessary in order to avoid the PCA dialog?  Or might I still be doing something wrong?**

Comment: +1. Good question, but imgur image is gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx) describes the many conditions that can cause the Program Compatibility Assistant to kick in.  I would review the set of scenarios that it describes and see whether any of them apply to your program.  I do see causes for PCA dialogs outside of the conditions you ruled out (e.g., attempting to create a new folder under `%ProgramFiles%`).